# Remove periods, commas, and hyphens from string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Tried those, however, I am still coming up with empty strings at very specific points in the code.

Here is the code:

```
beg=document.twocities.begins.value;
len_beg=beg.length;

var beg = beg.replace(/.,-/g," ");
```

1.

```
var beg_array=beg.split(" ");
ans1.innerHTML=beg_array.length;
```

2.

```
ans2.innerHTML=beg_array[0]+" "+beg_array[116];
```

3.

```
ans3.innerHTML=beg_array;
```

4.

```
beg_upper=beg.toUpperCase();
ans4.innerHTML=beg_upper;
```

Here is the output:

```
1. 116 
2. It undefined 
3. It,was,the,best,of,times,,it,was,the,worst,of,times, it,was,the,age,of,wisdom,,it,was,the,age,of,foolishness, it,was,the,epoch,of,belief,,it,was,the,epoch,of,incredulity,, it,was,the,season,of,Light,,it,was,the,season,of,Darkness,, it,was,the,spring,of,hope,,it,was,the,winter,of,despair,, we,had,everything,before,us,,we,had,nothing,before,us, we,were,all,going,direct,to,Heaven,,we,were,all,going,direct,the,other,way,-- in,short,,the,period,was,so,far,like,the,present,period,, that,some,of,its,noisiest,authorities,insisted,on,its,being,received,, for,good,or,for,evil,,in,the,superlative,degree,of,comparison,only. 
4. IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES, IT WAS THE WORST OF TIMES, IT WAS THE AGE OF WISDOM, IT WAS THE AGE OF FOOLISHNESS, IT WAS THE EPOCH OF BELIEF, IT WAS THE EPOCH OF INCREDULITY, IT WAS THE SEASON OF LIGHT, IT WAS THE SEASON OF DARKNESS, IT WAS THE SPRING OF HOPE, IT WAS THE WINTER OF DESPAIR, WE HAD EVERYTHING BEFORE US, WE HAD NOTHING BEFORE US, WE WERE ALL GOING DIRECT TO HEAVEN, WE WERE ALL GOING DIRECT THE OTHER WAY -- IN SHORT, THE PERIOD WAS SO FAR LIKE THE PRESENT PERIOD, THAT SOME OF ITS NOISIEST AUTHORITIES INSISTED ON ITS BEING RECEIVED, FOR GOOD OR FOR EVIL, IN THE SUPERLATIVE DEGREE OF COMPARISON ONLY.
```

Comment: Post your code as text or SO snippet.

Comment: Suggesting reading a good regexp tutorial such as that found on MDN. Look at character classes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `,.-` (using `[]` list)

```js
var string = "Th.is,, ,,is .so---me- -ni-ce. ..str,in.g";
var fixed  = string.replace(/[,.-]/g, '');
console.log( fixed ); // "This is some nice string"
```

Remove all `,.-` (using `|` alternatives. Here you need to `\` escape the `.` token)

```js
var string = "Th.is,, ,,is .so---me- -ni-ce. ..str,in.g";
var fixed  = string.replace(/,|\.|-/g, '');
console.log( fixed ); // "This is some nice string"
```

Remove anything but a-z A-Z charaters and `\s` spaces

```js
var string = "Th.is,, ,,is .so---me- -ni-ce. ..str,in.g";
var fixed  = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
console.log( fixed ); // "This is some nice string"
```

Remove anything but a-z (`i` case insensitive flag) charaters and `\s` spaces

```js
var string = "Th.is,, ,,is .so---me- -ni-ce. ..str,in.g";
var fixed  = string.replace(/[^a-z\s]/ig, '');
console.log( fixed ); // "This is some nice string"
```